# Difference Constraints

Tags: constraints, difference

I'm studying for my algorithms final and I came across a practice problem that I can't seem to figure out. Here's the problem:

> Consider the following set of difference constraints:
>
> ```
> x1 - x4 <= 1  
> x2 - x1 <= 2  
> x2 - x4 <= 0  
> x3 - x1 <= 1  
> x4 - x1 <= -1  
> x4 - x3 <= -2
> ```
>
> What is the solution that will be provided by the shortest path based algorithm for this set of constraints?

The answer that I got when I first did this was that `x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = -2`, and `x4 = -1`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because of the third constraint.

Can someone walk me through how to get the right answer using the shortest path based algorithm for this question? Thanks!

Comment: did you check http://programmers.stackexchange.com/? pleasecheck their help center to see if it's on-topic before asking

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I did not check that before I posted this question, but I just checked it now and I didn't find any previously asked questions that really helped me.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this exactly relates to shortest path...I'm seeing it relate to a system of equations which is easily solvable.  I'm also not 100% convinced that it'd be on-topic for Programmers.SE, either.

Comment: @Makoto In my textbook, it says that you are supposed to make a graph from the constraints, so there is an edge for each constraint. So, for example, for the first constraint listed, there would be an edge from x4 to x1 with a weight of 1. Once you have the entire graph, you are supposed to run a shortest path algorithm on it and it somehow gets you the answer. That's the part I don't understand. Any ideas?